# make .replaceFirst() start after a specific character

Tags: java, regex

Is there any way I can make .replaceFirst() start to replace only a after a specific string? e.g. I know that regex don't do well with html, and i have html text consisting of 1 h2 head and one paragraph. 
Now the keywords i replace using my software work flawlessly, however sometimes the keywords are also replaced within the title. Is there any way to make java know to start raplacing AFTER the very first

```
</h2>
```

String?

Comment: well.. from the top of my head.. do `indexOf()` to get the first `h2` and then take a substring after that until the end. Then replace the substring and then merge it with the original one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a regex to solution (so that it makes no difference if you use `replaceFirst()` or `replaceAll()`), I can suggest using capture groups:

`(?s)(<\/h2.+)\b(keyword)\b(?=.*<\/h2>.*$)`

```
 String regex = "(?s)(<\\/h2.+)\\b(keyword)\\b(?=.*<\\/h2>.*$)";
```

Replace the "keyword" with your word, and use "$1[replacement_keyword]" as a replacement string.

Here is a [code example](https://ideone.com/EALONW):

```
String input = "<title>Replacing keywords with keyword</title>\n"+
               "<body>\n"+
               "<h2>Titles</h2>\n"+
               "<p>Par with keywords and keyword</p>\n"+
               "<h2>Titles</h2>\n"+
               "<p>Par with keywords and keyword</p>\n"+
               "</body>";
String regex = "(?s)(<\\/h2.+)\\b(keyword)\\b(?=.*<\\/h2>.*$)";
String keytoreplacewith = "NEW_COOL_KEYWORD";
String output = input.replaceFirst(regex, "$1"+keytoreplacewith);
System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
<title>Replacing keywords with keyword</title>
<body>
<h2>Titles</h2>
<p>Par with keywords and NEW_COOL_KEYWORD</p>
<h2>Titles</h2>
<p>Par with keywords and keyword</p>
</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't work... the replacing of the keyword isn't done... (I call it like this:   text.replaceFirst("(?s)(<\\/h2.+)\\b("+myKeyword+")\\b(?=.*<\\/h2>.*$)", "$1["+keytoreplacewith+"]"); )

Comment: Ok, I added the sample code and a link to the sample program.